# Heatmap chart Apexcharts

Tags: jquery, charts, heatmap, apexcharts

I am trying to plot heatmap color based on condition and I am using the below code,
I am getting below values in console for `heatmapData` and need to plot that in heatmap,

```
0
: 
{x: '2024-02-26', y: '24FEBFUT', value: 1, fillColor: '#000000'}
1
: 
{x: '2024-02-25', y: '24FEBFUT', value: 1, fillColor: '#00FF00'}
2
: 
{x: '2024-02-24', y: '24FEBFUT', value: 1, fillColor: '#000000'}
length
: 
3
```

```
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
        <script>
            var heatmapData = @json($heatmapData);

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'heatmap',
                    height: 350
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Heatmap Data',
                    data: heatmapData.map(data => ({
                        x: data.last_trade_time,
                        y: data.symbol,
                        value: 1,
                        fillColor: data.color // Assign the color
                    }))
                }],
                xaxis: {
                    type: 'Date',
                    categories: heatmapData.map(data => data.last_trade_time),
                },
                yaxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: heatmapData.map(data => data.symbol),
                    title: {
                        text: 'Y-Axis'
                    }
                }
            };
                
            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
            chart.render();
        </script>
```

I am getting dates in X axis, but on Y axis I could not see symbol that is `24FEBFUT`, and based on date(X) and Symbol(Y), I need to plot color for box as fillColor, but I am not getting color box and Y axis,

How to get that?

Comment: Hi, can you make your code runnable it will easy to check what exactly is the issue ?